# Trouble with creating new attributes on large shapefile?

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, qgis-2.18

I have a point shapefile with ~2.5 million points.  I am creating a new attribute converting ft to m, and QGIS (2.18.15) is having trouble working with the datasets.  I have seen suggestions to only do this through the main window, which sped up the creation of the attribute, but now the hangup seems to be saving the changes.  This has been occupying 30 of the write capacity of my hard drive for over 30 minutes now.

Do I just need to be more patient or is this an issue with QGIS?  I did this previously when I had access to ArcGIS and it went pretty quickly.

Comment: is it possible that your shapefile is now over 2Gb? maybe use a virtual attribute to save space and the need to resave?

Comment: I don't think that is the case.  I just got to my computer after letting the save operation run all night, and it was STILL using up my hard drive read/write.  What I don't get is that the file size was only about .3 gb (for all of the files), so obviously it wasn't actually writing the whole time.

Comment: If the same process worked in ArcGIS, then it sounds like a bug in QGIS. You can check the [QGIS bug report page](issues.qgis.org) to see if this is a known bug, and the status of fixing it. If it's not reported, please make a bug report. In the meantime, maybe try exporting to a different file type like geopackage.

Comment: Looks like this issue is documented in a few places: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15292 
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/18406 
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20008 

But this one seems the closest to what I describe:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19771 

Doesn't look like there is a real fix at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** *The answer below is valid for QGIS 3 versions older than 3.4 (Madeira). In version 3.4 the time for adding a new attribute into the test dataset takes about 2 minutes when it took 12 minutes with QGIS 3.2.3.*

I made a test with QGIS 3.2.3 on Windows by editing a shapefile with about million points and dbf table of size 600 MB and I can confirm your findings. Steps and timings:

- Open the shapefile
- Open the attribute table - takes about 30 seconds
- Add a new field - takes about 15 seconds
- Now the attribute table is empty and nothing shows for 30 seconds
- QGIS shows a message that it is loading the attributes for 10 seconds
- Attribute table shows as empty and QGIS does not respond for more than 10 minutes. During all this time qgis-bin.exe is taking 25% of the CPU time of my computer. Attributes do appear after a long wait and it is possible to save the edits.

Adding a new field and saving the edits with OpenJUMP took less than 30 seconds total but it is even faster to add a new column with GDAL command line. This command runs in 15 seconds for my test data

```
ogrinfo million_points.shp -sql "alter table million_points add column new_field string"
```

Using 15 minutes to something that can be done in 15 seconds is not good. I suggest to make a QGIS bug report. Do not forget to include a link to a dataset that can be used for re-producing the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think that something different is going on in my case since I used the main window to do the edits instead of the attribute table.  When I did try via the attribute table, I experienced the same general issues you describe here (high cpu load), but mine did not finish in a reasonable time period (~30 minutes) so I went with the main window route, leading me to my description of the problem above.  I will see what I can do about making a bug report, but will probably just try to do it in GDAL for the time being.

Comment: For anyone else looking for a solution here, the GDAL command worked pretty quickly.

Comment: This answer is outdated as of 3.4

Comment: @ndawson, confirmed with OSGeo4W version of 3.4.1. The slow part that took more than 10 minutes takes now about 1-2 minutes with the same data. Not to beat direct update with GDAL but much better now.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get openJUMP since I dont have access to freely install on my computer, but I found a quick workaround.

Instead of trying to save the changes in QGIS. just get the program to output the values in the attribute table,
Select All
Open Excel
Paste and save as CSV.

Not sure if u need it to be a shapefile but this is my current workaround. QGIS still hangs up for 20+ minutes and I don't have all day to just reduce my points, and add the X/Y so I can add the CSV point file in CAD.