# QGIS export selection to shapefiles is extremely slow; using only 5 to 10% CPU

Tags: qgis-processing, performance

I am using QGIS 3.2.3. I am trying to do some simple actions. Selecting by attribute and exporting to shapefiles. I am using a OSM file as a source which is barely 60MB. But for some reason the process is incredibly slow (as in, it runs for twenty minutes and only reaches 5% of the export). When I look at my task manager QGIS is only using between 5-10% I suspect this is not much, but I don't know how to increase it (or even if I should.) Should I make it use more CPU? Or should I find another way to speed it up?

Comment: Could you have a try with QGIS 2.18? QGIS 3 seems to be very slow in some opetation, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300499/trouble-with-creating-new-attributes-on-large-shapefile.

Comment: Try with QGIS 3.4.1 - there's been a number of fixes to .osm file handling. It's normal that you'll only see small overall CPU usage here, as a safe operation like this is always going to be limited to a single thread and cannot be made multithreaded.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to specify the number of CPUs on the system and the type and excess speed of the disk where the data resides.

Comment: He guys thanks for the help. I moved on to versio 3.4.1 and it worked fine. Thanks for helping me out!